# How to mount in TWRP?

Tags: twrp, mount

I've never mounted in TWRP, a [script](https://github.com/nvllsvm/freecyngn) advices doing so. Can I mount directly from TWRP's mount screen? I can select the **partitions to mount**, but see no option execute.
Does rebooting/booting to the system the device mount the selected storage partitions?

Comment: As soon as you check (tick) the entry of a partition, it is mounted. If you untick the entry, the partition is unmounted.

Comment: @Firelord: You can post as an answer. Cache is enabled by default, should I keep it enabled (I have to mount data)?

Comment: @user598527 Leaving a partition mounted or not is a mere personal preference, as long as the partition itself isn't touched.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman: What do you mean? Should I "unmount" after mounting once?

Comment: @user598527 I mean that, if the script doesn't make changes to a partition's content, then mounting or unmounting it is irrelevant and you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: @user598527 Death is right. Mounting has no impact but only if the install does not effect it. I just mount SD/OTG to make backups, and leave the rest as-is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can I mount directly from TWRP's mount screen?

Yes. Under the category *Mount* you would see a range of partitions available to be mounted. Selecting an entry (check-mark) would automatically mount the corresponding partition and deselecting the entry would unmount that partition. You can mount/unmount multiple partitions.

You can verify the said method by executing the command `mount` when selecting/deselecting the partition(s), via [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) or through *Advanced* tab → *Terminal Command*.